# Content Type Column Removal

Tags: content-type, site-column

I have a few Content Types that inherit from a base Content Type. These are all wrapped up as part of my solution.

I wondered, as it is possible to add additional columns to a child Content Type using FieldRefs, is it possible to remove a column for the child Content Type that is specified in the parent Content Type?

It can be done on the front-end but I wondered if I could do it as part of my deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly use a Feature Receiver to hide the Field (FieldRef) on your child Content Type.

It may be possible to put a FieldRef in the definition of the inheriting Content Type with the same ID as the field ref in the parent and set it to Hidden=True, but I have no idea if this works it's just speculation.

The Feature Receiver will definitely work (assuming you code it right!)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The hidden=true seems like a viable and straight for work around.

I will also have a look at a feature receiver. Thanks Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Try googling 'RemoveFieldRef'

I've been trying to do something similar. Heres an example of a 'Firm Page' content type that derives from the 'Page' content type in a publishing site. I am attempting to remove the contact details. It isn't working for some reason but i think its the way its meant to be accomplished.
Hope this helps..

```
<ContentType ID="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39001C6234A536D8468dB0EE7E40FFDEEA45"
           Name="Firm Page"
           Group="Firm Content Types"
           Description=""
           Inherits="TRUE"
           Version="1">
<FieldRefs>

  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{aea1a4dd-0f19-417d-8721-95a1d28762ab}" Name="PublishingContact"/>
  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{c79dba91-e60b-400e-973d-c6d06f192720}" Name="PublishingContactEmail"/>
  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{7546ad0d-6c33-4501-b470-fb3003ca14ba}" Name="PublishingContactName"/>
  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{dc47d55f-9bf9-494a-8d5b-e619214dd19a}" Name="PublishingContactPicture"/>
  <RemoveFieldRef ID="{543bc2cf-1f30-488e-8f25-6fe3b689d9ac}" Name="PublishingRollupImage"/>

</FieldRefs>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also tried Pete's recommendation in my Visual Studio sharepoint solution. Adding the RemoveFieldRef elements into my FieldRefs> element seems to have no effect whatsoever. Would like to know if anywone has further experience with this. I don't mind writing feature receiver code, but would prefer to declare what I can.